# More php sites and one template

Tags: php, html, css

I write my template in `index.php` using bootstrap.
In this template there is a place `<div id="content"></div>` which is dynamic content of this site.

It means that, there I want to change the content.

Other for **login.php** , **register.php**, **news.php** page etc...

Okey I can copy this template(from index.php) to all of these pages but it is not good idea. If I want to change something static (like menu) I should do it in all pages.
I can use mysql to generate menu of course, **but I want to include other pages (which is need) to index.php content div**

Best Regards.

---

Okey I have one template (in html + js - bootstrap) which have static  elements for example navbar, logo etc...

But this template have one dynamic element I mean - div = content it change depending on which site is user watching (login.php,register.php etc...)

How to include this template to all subpages for example login.php,register.php etc... without copy and paste it everywhere ?

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution could be to create a layout.php page containing your whole template, and just put a  where your content is supposed to be.

Then, on each page, set your $content variable with the html of your page and just include layout.php then. A better solution is to implement the MVC design pattern, but it's more "complicated".

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, I find that it's best to break down every component of the page, for example I'll have

```
<?php
$pageTitle = "MyAwesomeWebpage";
require_once('header.php'); //Contains Doctype, HTML header tags
require_once('navbar.php'); //Contains navigation
?>
// Unique content here
<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

header.php example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><!-- ended in footer.php -->
<meta content= .... />
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" />
<!-- .... Other links and styles here -->
<body> <!-- ended in footer.php -->
```